# Unable to build an android app for a specific android version using Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I am going to make a program for the specific android version 8.1, and I don't really need to support any other versions of android. It's a specific use case for that version.

I have tried to set both the compileSdkVersion, and compileSdkVersion to 27, in the config.xml file. I have also tried 27.0.3.

```
       <platform name="android">
           <preference name="android-compileSdkVersion" value="27" />
           <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="27" />
       </platform>
```

I have also removed the android project, and added it back in after that.

According to people online this seems to be the general understanding of compiled and target Sdk version:

"Late to the game.. and there are several great answers above-- essentially, that the compileSdkVersion is the version of the API the app is compiled against, while the targetSdkVersion indicates the version that the app was tested against."

People are mentioning to change things the build.grapple file, but in my case it seems like there is only generated code in there, and it doesn't seem like I should change anything.

```
android {
namespace cordovaConfig.PACKAGE_NAMESPACE

defaultConfig {
    versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
    applicationId cordovaConfig.PACKAGE_NAMESPACE

    minSdkVersion cordovaConfig.MIN_SDK_VERSION
    if (cordovaConfig.MAX_SDK_VERSION != null) {
        maxSdkVersion cordovaConfig.MAX_SDK_VERSION
    }
    targetSdkVersion cordovaConfig.SDK_VERSION
    compileSdkVersion cordovaConfig.COMPILE_SDK_VERSION
}

lintOptions {
  abortOnError false
}

buildToolsVersion cordovaConfig.BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

// This code exists for Crosswalk and other Native APIs.
// By default, we multiply the existing version code in the
// Android Manifest by 10 and add a number for each architecture.
// If you are not using Crosswalk or SQLite, you can
// ignore this chunk of code, and your version codes will be respected.

if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
    flavorDimensions "default"

    productFlavors {
        armeabi {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 1
            ndk {
                abiFilters = ["armeabi"]
            }
        }
        armv7 {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
            ndk {
                abiFilters = ["armeabi-v7a"]
            }
        }
        arm64 {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 3
            ndk {
                abiFilters = ["arm64-v8a"]
            }
        }
        x86 {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
            ndk {
                abiFilters = ["x86"]
            }
        }
        x86_64 {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 5
            ndk {
                abiFilters = ["x86_64"]
            }
        }
    }
} else if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)) {
    // This provides compatibility to the default logic for versionCode before cordova-android 5.2.0
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
            keyAlias = ""
            keyPassword = ""
            storeFile = null
            storePassword = ""
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
}

if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
    addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
```

}

This is the error that I am getting:

```
       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

       * What went wrong:
       Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
       > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
       > 17 issues were found when checking AAR metadata:

   1.  Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 33, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

   2.  Dependency 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 33, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

   3.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 31, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

   4.  Dependency 'androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 33, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

   5.  Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 32, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

   6.  Dependency 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 32 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 32, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

   7.  Dependency 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.6.0' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 33, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

   8.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 31, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

   9.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.5.1' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 31, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

  10.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 33, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

  11.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 33, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

  12.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.4.1' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 31, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

  13.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.5.1' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 31, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

  14.  Dependency 'androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.2.0' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 31, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

  15.  Dependency 'androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 31, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

  16.  Dependency 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.5.1' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 31 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 31, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).

  17.  Dependency 'androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0' requires libraries and applications that
       depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the
       Android APIs.

       :app is currently compiled against android-27.

       Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
       of at least 33, for example 33.

       Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
       allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
       targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
       minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
       on).
```

Comment: The errors you are getting basically tell you that you have dependencies on libraries that need newer compileSdkVersion. You can compile with the latest version, even if you only want to target/support something older.

Comment: @DavidWasser 
Should I not be changing any of the settings? I tried to only set the target one, and then it also fails with the same errors. 

When I only set the target one it compiles like this:

Android Target SDK: android-33
Android Compile SDK: 27

I can test the opposite as well, but then I get this error:

he "android-compileSdkVersion" (27) should be greater than or equal to the "android-targetSdkVersion" (33).

Comment: You can also target latest (33) if you want. As long as you don't use any libraries that have minSDK > 27 you should be fine. In any case the compile SDK MUST be >= the target SDK. To be sure that your code runs on Android 8.1, you should set minSDK to 27.

Comment: @DavidWasser 

I set the minsdk 27, and it built sucessfully. What libraries are we talking about here? I am just using html, css and javascript, so are we talking about those libraries? Or are we talking about the libraries the cordona android libraries, and plugins?

I have just built with the default generated project, which is a tiny project.

Comment: Sounds good. The libraries I'm referring to are the libraries in your gradle dependencies. You can see them in the list of errors. Basically all the androidx libraries like `androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1`